# Как записать воспроизводимый звук в файл?

Tags: c#, unity3d, звукозапись, unity3d-ui

У меня есть программа для Android с клавишами (UI-Button). На них наложен C#-код для воспроизведения заданных звуков.

Мне нужно создать новую кнопку, которая при нажатии будет активировать запись звука воспроизводимого при нажатии на клавиши и сохранять результат в выбранную папку.

Код для клавиш:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class Keys : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler {

    public AudioClip Sound;

    public Button button { get { return GetComponent<Button>(); } }
    public AudioSource source { get { return GetComponent<AudioSource>(); } }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ((IPointerDownHandler)button).OnPointerDown(eventData);
        source.PlayOneShot(Sound);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        source.clip = Sound;
        source.playOnAwake = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Start () {
    string [] dev = Microphone.devices;
    string micro = dev[0];


   /* foreach (string a in dev)
    {
        Debug.Log(a); 
    }
    вывод всех микрофонов в консоль, если приспичит потестить на коспе
    */
    Microphone.Start(micro,false,10, 44100);

    //micro - микрофон выбирает самый первый в списке
    //false - стоит ли продолжать запись после 10 сек
    //10 - сек время воспроизведения
    //44100 - Частота дискретизации аудиоклипа
    //так же применимо для source
    source = Microphone.Start(micro,false,10, 44100);  
}
```